# Maven archive multiple war containing different files

Tags: java, spring, maven, jenkins, war

I have a maven project containing among resources three files as follow:

```
src/main/webapp/file.xml
src/main/webapp/fileA.xml
src/main/webapp/fileB.xml
```

My goal is to archive three different war packages with the same jenkins task where for each one the resource file is renamed and called as `file.xml`.

The result should be:

```
package-with-file.war
package-with-fileA.war
package-with-fileB.war
```

- first package should remove `fileA.xml` and `fileB.xml`
- second should remove `file.xml` and `fileB.xml`, and rename `fileA.xml` in `file.xml`
- third  should remove `file.xml` and `fileA.xml`, and rename `fileB.xml` in `file.xml`

I thing a way could be using `profiles` and using the `maven-deploy-plugin` defining a different `classifier` and `filename` for each package, but i cannot understand how to rename files before.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
  [...]
  <configuration>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <classifier>fileA</classifier>
    <file>
       ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-fileA.war
    </file>
  </configuration>
  [...]
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put the files in 3 different directories: `src/main/webapp-A|B|C/file.xml`
Then write 3 different executions of maven-war-plugin each adding one of these directories like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <webResources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp-A</directory>
            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </webResources>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

-- edit 1 --

I don't think it is possible from one directory. You have to either use different directories or you have different names for the files.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution, but i forgot to mention that the file MUST stay into the directory src/main/webapp/file.xml. I cannot change the directory by now. The war plugin would copy the content of the directory to the path or would use the directory as is?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do the "file include and exclude part" is something that can be easily done using maven shade plugin for [reference](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html).

Renaming a file is something that can be done using a dedicated plugin http://code.google.com/p/maven-file-rename-plugin/.

Comment: could you provide an example?